# Phonegap and xml files to design mode in mobile project

Tags: android, xml, linux, eclipse, cordova

I am using Phonegap to start a new mobile project:

```
phonegap create myproject
```

And eclipse to Create new project based on existing source code.

But have no xml files in the source to edit in design mode in eclipse.

What I need to do?
I need to create it? where?

I do not have found post nor documentation for guess anything.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find any design files.

With PhoneGap you create your application in html/javascript/css.
You'll find those files in the /www folder.

To turn that into a real function app you can run the `phonegap build` CLI tool.

Should give you something like this;

```
$ phonegap build ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the iOS platform...
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
[phonegap] successfully compiled iOS app
```